# convert an associative and indexed array into an associative array

Tags: php

```
   Array ( [0] => Array ( [pkg_id] => 00004 [0] => 00004 [food_cat] => 
    starter  [1] => starter [max_price] => 2 [2] => 2 [max_item] => 2 [3] => 
    2 [sub_text] => select any 1 [4] => select any 1 [display_seq] => 1 [5] 
    => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [pkg_id] => 00004 [0] => 00004 [food_cat] => main 
    course [1] => main course [max_price] => 6 [2] => 6 [max_item] => 4 [3] 
    => 4 [sub_text] => select any 3 [4] => select any 3 [display_seq] => 2 
    [5] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [pkg_id] => 00004 [0] => 00004 [food_cat] => 
    desert [1] => desert [max_price] => 3 [2] => 3 [max_item] => 2 [3] => 2 
    [sub_text] => select any 1 [4] => select any 1 [display_seq] => 3 [5] => 
    3 ) )
```

here is an array which is formed when i ran a select query in the database. The query result forms an array which is combination of associated and indexed array both. You can see the repetition of values.
i want that is there any method to covert this array into only associative array?

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve that ? Also don't use irrelevant tags like `javascript`. Its not related to Js as per your description.

Comment: not exactly
i have noticed this because it is causing problem in my further program

Comment: can you post which mysql function are you using to fetch data?

Comment: use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array if you are using mysql. if you are using mysqli use mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: show your code (the php, the db schema).

Comment: use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` for fetching the data

Comment: $conn=newPDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
$conn>setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt=$conn->prepare("select * from food_package_details where pkg_id=:pkgid"); 
$stmt->bindparam(":pkgid",$pkg);
i have used PDO with Prepare

Comment: Your code output is very hard to read; please try to pretty-print it to get more help.

Comment: Its always good to get this from the horses mouth so to speak... Assuming and hoping you are using mysqli_xxx if you are using mysqlx_xxx - have a read of this... http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: @smat88dd i have just establish the connection and through the PDO Prepare ran a select query. The query is stored in a variable and Through print_r() i have printed the array whose output is shown in my question

Comment: ... then you should try to re-format it with correct linebreaks after each value; sorry cant give you an example in this comments section it ignores line-breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `$stmt->->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` to fetch assoc array.Use below code:

```
$conn=newPDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$userna‌​me,$password);
$conn>setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)‌​; 
$stmt=$conn->prepare("select * from food_package_details where pkg_id=:pkgid");
$stmt->bindparam(":pkgid",$pkg);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC:`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)  fetch_style

like

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned
>   in your result set

check all PDOStatement::fetch [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)